# Where to put property file in config folder of tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using a spring boot project where I have two module Search and Web. I build war from web module and search module in injected as jar. I have a property file index.properties in search module, So every time I make a jar it goes into search jar, But I want to remove this jar from Search module and want to externalise it to config folder of tomcat. I am using sprinboot project, I don't know how to do this.

```
System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "search_index");
```

Does doing this will work ?

Comment: Can you re frame it clearly?I want to remove this jar from Search module and want to externalise it to config folder of tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly

1) You would like to externalized .properties file

2) And you don't want to include .properties in jar file

To answer the first issue there are multiple ways to externalized props file
Try - **spring.config.location**
Either set this value from your main method or - Inside Tomcat put following value in **setenv.sh**

```
Dspring.config.location=/filelocation/application.properties
```

Reference - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

To solve the second problem try using exclusion tag in maven config.
like -

```
<excludes>
<exclude>*.properties</exclude>
</excludes>
```

My answer is based on the brief understanding provided by you, Please post all the specifics which will helpful to provide correct solution for the issue.